# ast.literal_eval same behavior as eval

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

I'm trying to achieve the same behavior with ast.literal_eval as with eval, is it possible somehow?

```
import ast
class MyClass():
    ...


class_string = "MyClass"

eval_clas = eval(class_string)
print(eval_clas)

ast_class = ast.literal_eval(class_string)
print(ast_class)
```

the output of eval_class:

```
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

When I try to do the same thing with literal_eval I'm getting

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f1670b9a520>
```

Comment: This is not possible, `ast.literal_eval` only parses "literals" i.e. things like a quoted string `"hello"` or a list `[1, 2, 3]`.  Unfortunately the name of your class is not a "literal" in Python terms.

Comment: if you take a step back and describe _why_ you want this it may be possible to offer an alternative suggestion

Comment: @Anentropic I'm parsing some code with AST and extracting names of the classes as strings, after that I want to create instances of those classes ,but i don't want to use eval

Comment: If you want a function that behaves exactly like `eval`, use `eval`. Except, don't.

Comment: @tobias_k for security reasons i don't wan to use eval, that's why I'm searching for similar  approach

Comment: I understand that, but if you want "the same behaviour", that's `eval`. If you want a subset of `eval` behavior, that's not in `literal_eval`, please be more specific, maybe it can be helped. Even better: describe _what_ you need it _for_.

Comment: @tobias_k i described in comment above

Comment: If the classes are already in scope you could get them by string name from the `globals()` dict.  If the classes are in some module that has been imported you could `getattr(the_module, class_name)`

Comment: But "creating the classes", i.e. invoking their `__init__` methods, could entail all kinds of stuff that `literal_eval` can and _should_ not do.

Comment: Then your question should be, for example, "how do I get a class object from its name?". What you actually asked is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) which leads to unhelpful answers.

Comment: Once you have the class, what will you do with it? Should the class be part of an expression to be "safely" evaluated, or do you just want to safely evaluate the parameters for the constructor? Please show a full example of what you want to evaluate.

Comment: `literal_eval` can only evaluate literal expressions that do not contain variables — so you can't achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ast.literal_eval` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) claims that

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
> literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
> consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
> numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, `None` and `Ellipsis`.

custom classes are not supported by that function, as they are not enumerated